# Change language in Roomle Configurator

Tags: javascript, roomle

I use the following code to instantiate the Roomle Configurator on my website:

```
    <iframe
      src="https://www.roomle.com/t/cp/?id=<ID>&configuratorId=<CONFIGURATOR_ID>&api=false"
      frameborder="0"
      width="100%"
      height="500"
    />
```

By default the configurator always uses the default browser language. Is it possible to change that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to use the `locale` url param to set the language.

```
   <iframe
      src="https://www.roomle.com/t/cp/?id=<ID>&configuratorId=<CONFIGURATOR_ID>&api=false&locale=en"
      frameborder="0"
      width="100%"
      height="500"
    />
```

Here is a list with all available languages: https://www.roomle.com/en/documentation/configurator-languages